# Как подключить либу к своему проекту?

Tags: c++, cmake

Редко пользуюсь CMake. Вроде всё просто. Но тут вдруг вылезла ошибка, с которой не могу справиться:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_subdirectory):
add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source
directory "C:/projects/cmake/foo/src" is not a subdirectory of
"C:/projects/cmake/app/src". When specifying an out-of-tree source a
binary directory must be explicitly specified.
```

Библиотека foo лежит в той же папке, что и приложение app. Ошибка исчезает, если поместить библиотеку внутрь app/src. Структура каталогов такая:

```
|-- app/src
|-- foo/src
```

В папке app/src лежат файлы

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
project(hello_world)                
set(SOURCE_EXE main.cpp)
include_directories(../../foo/src)
add_executable(main ${SOURCE_EXE})
add_subdirectory(../../foo/src)
target_link_libraries(main foo)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  hello_world();
  return 0;
}
```

В папке foo/src лежат файлы

CMakeLists.cpp:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(foo)                
set(SOURCE_LIB foo.cpp)     
add_library(foo STATIC ${SOURCE_LIB})
```

foo.h:

```
void hello_world();
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
void hello_world()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Как избавится от ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

Структура каталогов в каталоге сборки по умолчанию соответствует структуре каталогов исходников. В вашем случае корневой бинарник из проекта app будет лежать в корне каталога сборки, а foo тогда должен лежать в соседнем каталоге, но тогда он будет располагаться за пределами каталога сборки. Обычно проблема решается так: есть конечный проект (библиотека или приложение), который подключает зависимости при помощи target_link_libraries, и есть корневой проект, в котором уже указывается, где искать зависимости. При этом для изменения путей к либам не нужно модифицировать CMakeLists основного проекта. Структура должна быть примерно такая:

```
project
|- CMakeLists #1
|- src
|- |- CMakeLists #2
|- libs
|- |- CMakeLists #3
```

Сборка должна запускаться для CMakeLists #1.
В CMakeLists #1 сначала идет поиск библиотек, затем add_subdirectory(src). Библиотеки можно прописывать либо напрямую в  CMakeLists #1, либо можно добавить дочерний проект с библиотеками при помощи add_subdirectory(libs), и прописывать пути к либам в CMakeLists #3.

Только нужно помнить, что порядок в CMake имеет значение.